# Angular Routing to the wrong path when redirected

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router-guards

Angular 8.2.14

So I have a problem with my angular routing, here is the code from my routing-module:

```
  { 
    path: "hero", 
    component: HeroListComponent, 
    canActivate: [AuthGuard], 
    children: [
      { 
        path: "new", 
        component: NewHeroComponent
      },
      { 
        path: ":id", 
        component: HeroComponent, 
        canActivate: [HeroGuard]
      }
    ],
  },
```

My problem is that I have a button on another website that redirects me to my Angular app, when the button is clicked, it opens a new tab with a url like this:

http://localhost:4200/hero/new?power=123&attr=123%20456%20789&city=123&rt=1&rate=80

When the user is already logged in, the routing module works fine and brings him to the NewHeroComponent properly and handles the params of the query correctly.

**The problem occurs when the user isn't logged** in and has to go through the authentication process, normally the redirection is done without any problem for the other components but for some reason in this case the router tries to open the HeroComponent.

When I log the ActivatedRouteSnapshot in my HeroGuard (which isn't supposed to be called but still is) I get this:

```
params:
  id: "new?power=123&attr=123%20456%20789&city=123&rt=1&rate=80"
```

The redirection is pretty simple, the link is kept in localStorage when the user isn't logged in and the redirection is done in my main component after the user logs in if the localStorage key for my redirection is set by using ***this.router.navigate([route])***.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: console log the route getting passed to navigate.

Comment: It's the good one, "/hero/new?power=123&attr=123%20456%20789&city=123&rt=1&rate=80"

Comment: what's the current url from which this is called?

Comment: and in normal case on which url you go to to activate herocomponent.

Comment: in normal logged in case were you normally able to go to newherocomponent?

Comment: -It's called from the root url (localhost:4200);  
-On normal cases, I access HeroComponent from /hero, I select a Hero and it brings me to /hero/123;  
-And yes, I was able to access it without any problems

Comment: I think I found the reason of the problem but not the solution: when navigate is called, it changes the url ? for %3F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research, I found that I used the wrong function to navigate.

The problem: the ? in the url was changed for %3F when `router.navigate([route])` was called, result of this was that angular thought it was a parameter.

The solution: I changed `router.navigate([route])` to `router.navigateByUrl(route)`

Comment: You can achieve the same with `router.navigate`: `router.navigate([route], { queryParams: { ... } })`